# Не могу разобраться с одном алгоритмом насчет матриц, PHP

Tags: php, массивы, матрицы

Задача у меня стоит такая:

```
//  В заданных строках прямоугольной матрицы перенести максимальный элемент в последнюю
//  позицию строки, сдвинув при этом влево расположенные после него элементы.
```

Я реализовал логику поиска максимального элемента в строке матрицы (указанной, по ее индексу), но что есть сдвигом? Что присваивается самому правому элементу в этом случае?

Прошу подсказки.

Answer (score 0):

Было

```
a   b   c  max  d  e  f
```

должно стать:

```
a   b   c  d  e  f  max
```

Для длины строки n и индекса максимума k:

```
 $tmp = $arr[k];
 for ($i = k; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
      $arr[$i] = $arr[$i + 1];
 }
 $arr[$n - 1] = $tmp;
```

Comment: я думаю как мне адекватно сделать сдвиг, как так умело бегать по строке матрице. ...

Comment: Что-то непонятно осталось?